# Select2 issue with posting data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using `select2` for a tagging system.

I have come across the issue wherein **whenever I submit my form, no data from the select2 field is posted**, however if I do not include the `select2 js` such that the input is "normal" then the field submits properly.

I confirmed this by printing the post data after submit. Is there something I'm missing to handle select2 posts?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#tags").select2({
        tags:["red", "green", "blue"]
    });
});
</script>
```

Excerpt of HTML:

```
<div class="control-group"><label class="control-label">Project tags</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi" id="tags" style="width:300px;">
            <ul class="select2-choices">
                <li class="select2-search-field">
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" placeholder="" id="project_tags" name="    project_tags">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select the id of your input field instead of the div:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#project_tags").select2({tags:["red", "green", "blue"]});
  });
</script>
```